# Как завернуть в <span> первое слово?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Мне срочно нужно завернуть первое слово в 
Нужен jQuery код, который выполнит данную задачу.
Заранее Спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениям `/^([^\s]*)/` или `/^(\w+|[[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)/`, или свой вариант (нужно тестировать под необходимое)

```js
$('#container').html( function(index, text){ return text.replace(/^([^\s]*)/, '<span>$1</span>')} );
```

```css
span {
color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">Вот такой у нас текст</div>
```

---

С позволения автора ответа внесу правку, как отметил Grundy, эстетичней:

```js
$('#container').html(function(index, text){ return text.replace(/^(\w+|[[а-яА-ЯёЁ]+)/, '<span>$1</span>'); });
```

```css
span {
color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">Вот такой у нас текст</div>
```

Comment: С регуляркой это хорошо придумано!

Comment: [.html(function)](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)

Comment: А вы только английский язык признаете языком? Подсказка, `\w` работает только для английского языка.

Comment: Хорошо, что обратили внимание. Адаптировала.

Comment: Извините, но в мире существуют и другие языки помимо русского и английского :-)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, не надо расширять задачу за автора :-) всех вариантов все равно не предусмотришь, так как сначала нужно определиться что именно является словом. А такого определения в вопросе нет

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, тогда подойдет вариант регулярного выражения в первой строке

Comment: @Grundy я не расширяю. Написано - слово. Решать, что именно является словом будем эмпирическим путем :-)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, вот автор ответа и решила эмпирически :-)

Comment: @Grundy да, повторюсь, какой вопрос, такой и ответ :-). А вообще, с `\s` регуляркой - уже лучше! А можно еще учесть момент, когда фраза начинается с пробела?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko кстати, c примером, что вы приводили в моём ответе `Привет.Я Маша.` этот вариант сработает корректно, зато наоборот, вот такие варианты `Math.PI приблизительно равно 3,14159.` или `5,5 литра молока` - тут будет "первым словом" только часть до точки и запятой, что нелогично

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич ваша правда, нелогично. Я вообще хотел подвести к тому, что такие плохо сформулированные (без конкретных use case) вопросы надо бы закрывать, ибо на них очень тяжело дать ответ.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let p = document.getElementById('p1');
let span1 = document.createElement('span');
let span2 = document.createElement('span');

let spanStr = p.textContent.split(' ')[0];


span1.textContent = spanStr + ' ';
span2.textContent = p.textContent.split(' ').splice(1).join(' ');
span2.classList.add('sr');
p.textContent = '';
p.appendChild(span1);
p.appendChild(span2);
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}

.sr {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">
  <p id="p1">This is a sentence</p>
</div>
```

Как это с jQuery этими проворачивать не знаю. На чистом JS как-то так после пары экспериментов придумал.

Comment: Постарайтесь добавить работающий пример.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, готово :-)

Comment: @Grundy молодец! Теперь можно минус ответу заслуженно ставить :-)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, почему? :-) работает ведь? В примере слово подкрасилось

Comment: Минусуйте, минусуйте! А ответ всё равно рабочий! ;) А как вот эту штуку про `выполнить код` вставить я просто ещё не разобрался.

Comment: @Grundy программирование - великая вещь. Да, работает просто на загляденье! Какой вопрос - такой и ответ, все верно. Но минус все равно пока не сниму - надо стараться делать этот мир чуточку лучше.

Comment: @AlexSazonov [Что такое сниппеты?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/186999)